# .ThenInclude().ThenInclude()-ed data is not loaded in LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I can't seem to load the products from `InFrontPages` on grandchild levels or deeper in this query. Products are loaded for the first level of sub categories, but for all deeper levels, it just returns `null`:

```
var categories = await _context.ProductCategories
        .Include(e => e.ProductInCategory)
            .ThenInclude(e => e.Product)
                .ThenInclude(f => f.InFrontPages)
        .AsQueryable() // <-- Force full execution (loading) of the above
        .Where(e => e.ParentId == id) // <-- then apply the parent id filter
        // (id can be `null` (for root categories), or a category Id)
        .OrderBy(o => o.SortOrder)
        .ToListAsync();
```

The models:

```
public class ProductCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(ParentCategory))]
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    public ProductCategory ParentCategory { get; set; } //nav.prop to parent
    public ICollection<ProductCategory> Children { get; set; } = new List<ProductCategory>();
    public ICollection<ProductInCategory> ProductInCategory { get; set; }
    public ICollection<FrontPageProduct> FrontPageProduct { get; set; }
}

public class ProductInCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int ProductCategoryId { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }

    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public ProductCategory ProductCategory { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ProductTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Info { get; set; }
    public string LongInfo { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int? Weight { get; set; }

    // A product can belong to multiple category front pages
    public ICollection<FrontPageProduct> InFrontPages { get; set; }

    // A product can belong to multiple categories
    public ICollection<ProductInCategory> InCategories { get; set; }
}

public class FrontPageProduct
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductCategoryId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }

    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public ProductCategory ProductCategory { get; set; }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Hey, `AsQueryable()` does not force anything, it should be `AsEnumerable()`.

Comment: @IvanStoev Indeed. It worked, however, now I can't run the query async anymore. The query is being executed in a ViewComponent, and that has to be async. Of course, I can call the ViewComponent async, and just omit the `await` keyword. It will run, but it seems like a bit of a hack ...

Comment: Hmm, may be then replace `AsQueryable()` with `ToAsyncEnumerable()` and `ToListAsync()` with `ToList()`?